What is the fastest way to filter out rows which do not meet condition in sql?
Let us say I have a table with structure
(
  id int,
  value int,
  key int
)

I want to leave only those rows, which correspond to id, which have certain key at least once. For example if desired key equals 5 then from table
id value key
1  1     1
1  1     2
2  1     5
2  3     2
3  5     4
3  5     5

I want to obtain result
id value key
2  1     5
2  3     2
3  5     4
3  5     5

because object with id 1 does not have 5 in key column while the other objects do.
I know 2 ways to do that, in both of them we create a tmp_table with needed ids like
select [distinct] id from example_table where key=5

and then either do filtering:
select * from example_table where id in tmp_table

or joining:
select e.* from example_table e join tmp_table t on e.id = t.id

For those scenarios I have several questions:

Is there a difference in performance between these two ways? Generally and in Vertica.
For joining method I must use distinct, otherwise data will be duplicated. Do I have to do it for the first method? From one hand distinct is expensive operation, from the other hand in should be faster (if there isn't some sort of hash table)
Is there any third way to achieve the desired result?


Generally? https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Why create a temp table and not simply use a subquery?

Test it, and find out?


Vertica performs optimizations, both IN and JOIN methods are likely to perform similarly.
If multiple rows can share the same id, DISTINCT is required for the joining method.
A different approach is to use EXISTS which avoids DISTINCT.

    SELECT e.* FROM example_table e
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM example_table WHERE id = e.id AND key = 5
    );

You can also use Vertica's EXPLAIN command to check the execution of different approaches.

Two additional ways:

Inner join with a full select of all ids of rows with value of 5:

WITH
id_s AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM indata
  WHERE key = 5
)
SELECT
  i.*
FROM indata i
INNER JOIN id_s USING(id)
;


WHERE IN(<fullselect>) predicate:


SELECT
  *
FROM indata
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM indata
  WHERE key=5
);

